# DropDown List in Client Detail Template - Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add dropdownlist in client template, but somehow not able, could someone please help me on this?

```
 columns.Bound(o => o.ImportFunctionText).ClientTemplate("# if (ImportFunction == 0) { # Account # } else if (ImportFunction == 1) { # Row # } #")
                      .EditorTemplateName("DropDownList")
                      .EditorViewData(new
                      {
                          Id = "ImportFunction",
                          Data = ViewBag.dropDownList,
                          FieldName = "value:ImportFunction"
                      })
                      .Width(210)
                      .Title("Function");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make use of editor templates you have to store your editor template within the folder ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/tmp_dropdown_attribute.cshtml as a partial view.

according to the telerik asp net mvc docs your should the template look like the following:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("Employee") // Name of the widget should be the same as the name of the property
.DataValueField("EmployeeID") // The value of the dropdown is taken from the EmployeeID property
.DataTextField("EmployeeName") // The text of the items is taken from the EmployeeName property
.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["employees"]) // A list of all employees which is populated in the controller
```

)

and your controller should bind the viewdata container within the controller method which generates the view like that:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
ViewData["employees"] = new NorthwindDataContext()
             .Employees
             .Select(e => new Employee
             {
                  EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID,
                  EmployeeName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
             })
             .OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeName);

return View();
}
```

for further reading please refer to the docs which can be found here:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates